# How to use unidecode in python (3.3)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to remove all non-ascii characters from a text document. I found a package that should do just that, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

It should accept a string and convert all non-ascii characters to the closest ascii character available. I used this same module in perl easily enough by just calling `while (<input>) { $_ = unidecode($_); }` and this one is a direct port of the perl module, the documentation indicates that it should work the same.

I'm sure this is something simple, I just don't understand enough about character and file encoding to know what the problem is. My origfile is encoded in UTF-8 (converted from UCS-2LE). The problem may have more to do with my lack of encoding knowledge and handling strings wrong than the module, hopefully someone can explain why though. I've tried everything I know without just randomly inserting code and search the errors I'm getting with no luck so far.

Here's my python

```
from unidecode import unidecode

def toascii():
    origfile = open(r'C:\log.convert', 'rb')
    convertfile = open(r'C:\log.toascii', 'wb')

    for line in origfile:
        line = unidecode(line)
        convertfile.write(line)

    origfile.close()
    convertfile.close()

toascii();
```

If I don't open the original file in byte mode (`origfile = open('file.txt','r'`) then I get an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1563: character maps to <undefined>` from the `for line in origfile:` line.

If I do open it in byte mode `'rb'` I get `TypeError: ord() expected string length 1, but int found` from the `line = unidecode(line)` line.

if I declare line as a string `line = unidecode(str(line))` then it will write to the file, but... not correctly. `\r\n'b'\xef\xbb\xbf[ 2013.10.05 16:18:01 ] User_Name > .\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\` It's writing out the \n, \r, etc and unicode characters instead of converting them to anything.

If I convert the line to string as above, and open the convertfile in byte mode `'wb'` it gives the error `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

If I open it in byte mode without declaring it a string `'wb'` and `unidecode(line)` then I get the `TypeError: ord() expected string length 1, but int found` error again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `unidecode` module accepts *unicode* string values and *returns* a unicode string in Python 3. You are giving it binary data instead. Decode to unicode or open the input text file in textmode, and encode the result to ASCII before writing it to a file, or open the output text file in text mode.

Quoting from the module documentation:

> The module exports a single function that takes an Unicode object (Python 2.x) or **string (Python 3.x)** and returns a string (**that can be encoded to ASCII bytes in Python 3.x**)

Emphasis mine.

This should work:

```
def toascii():
    with open(r'C:\log.convert', 'r', encoding='utf8') as origfile, open(r'C:\log.toascii', 'w', encoding='ascii') as convertfile:
        for line in origfile:
            line = unidecode(line)
            convertfile.write(line)
```

This opens the inputfile in text modus (using UTF8 encoding, which judging by your sample line is correct) and writes in text modus (encoding to ASCII).

You do need to explicitly specify the encoding of the file you are opening; if you omit the encoding the current system locale is used (the result of a `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` call), which usually won't be the correct codec if your code needs to be portable.

Comment: On first try it doesn't seem to work, I get the same problems as when I used str(), i.e. I end up with lines like `\r\n\xef\xbb\xbf`. I'll go see what I can do with those tips though.

Comment: @BeanBagKing: the `b'\xef\xbb\xbf'` you see is a representation of a bytes value; that means you are passing in the result of `str(bytevalue)`, not a unicode string value as decoded from the input file.

Comment: correct, somehow my original file was overwritten with those values. I'm still having errors with the code you gave though, `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1563: cha
racter maps to <undefined>`. If I open the file in byte mode I get the `expected string of length 1, but int found` Could this be a more fundamental problem with the encoding of my original file?

Comment: @BeanBagKing: What codec are you using to decode the file? Only reading the file can throw unicode decode exceptions in the sample code I gave here, but `'charmap' codec` indicates you are *not* using UTF-8 here to decode what looks to me to be UTF-8 data.

Comment: to decode them originally? The file was in UCS-2LE and I converted it to utf8 like so. `file.write(block.decode('utf-16').encode('utf8'))`. Notepad++ says the file is currently in UTF-8 without BOM. If you're talking about decoding the current file, that's every bit of my code in the question, I left nothing out.

Comment: @BeanBagKing: Then where does the exception come from you posted in your previous comment? There should have been no reason to re-encode the file, btw, not for Python in any case.

Comment: @BeanBagKing: Note that I never said the file wasn't in UTF-8, just that the exception you posted in a comment is *not* consistent with a decode error for UTF-8 data being decoded as UTF-8. Instead, it looks as if you are trying to decode UTF-8 data as *some other* codec.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40515/discussion-between-beanbagking-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: For anyone else who wonders by and reads this, the conversation was continued in discussion and the root problem ended up being that python 3 does not open a file in utf8 by default. The original file had to be explicitly opened in utf8 encoding, and the converted file in ascii encoding. Thanks Martijn.